# Errors using boost::math::ibeta

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I have boost_1_67_0 installed, and have used functions from lambda.hpp and also the regex library to confirm the header-only functions and also library-based functions are working properly.

However, the following code:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    boost::math::ibeta((double)5, (double)1, (double)0.5);
}
```

throws the error (Visual Studio Community 2017, 15.5.2):

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl boost::math::ibeta<double,double,double>(double,double,double)" (??$ibeta@NNN@math@boost@@YANNNN@Z) referenced in function _main ProjectName C:\PathToProject\ProjectName\main.obj   1   
LNK1120 1 unresolved externals
```

I tried reinstalling boost, recreating the project, switching between x86 and x64 (and debug/release), and using boost_1_66_0. Any other ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is ibeta in a particular library that I can confirm is present, or is it header-only?

Comment: Nice work, please edit the "answer" part out of the question and post it as a self-answer. That stuff is useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong include - I should use beta.hpp not gamma.hpp. The source of this error was an incorrect include listed in boost's documentation [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_beta/ibeta_function.html). The proper include for ibeta is

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/beta.hpp>
```

The correct documentation for ibeta is [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_beta/ibeta_function.html). The previous link is for an old version of boost (which Google links to if you [I] currently search for "boost ibeta").